# Dynamically enumerating values for a property in .Net

Tags: .net, enumeration, propertygrid

You know how a TreeView control's ImageList property lists all ImageLists on a form? I need something similar, but with a list of strings. It's like an enumeration, but defined at runtime, with the object that exposes the property in a PropertyGrid.

So, with a list of strings like { "foo", "bar", "grill" } the property should list those but if that list of strings is changed (say, add a "bbq" item), the property should enum { "foo", "bar", "grill", *"bbq"* } instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a list of strings you need, take a look at writing your own [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx). You'll need to override the `GetStandardValues` method.

Answer (score 1):

This [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/dropdownproperties.aspx) explains how to write a custom [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) or [`UITypeEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx).

Comment: A type editor is overkill. Just using a TypeConverter is much easier.

Comment: You can achieve a lot with UITypeEditor, but IME it's overkill for just a list of strings (for instance, you have to create a list control to hold the items). TypeConverter is pretty much automatic.

Comment: TypeConverters for combo boxes are covered in the article, too.